# Trying to hide CSS class, but then trying to display a sub class

Tags: css

So I've got this CSS:

```
.addthis_toolbox {
display: none;
}

.title_offeringHope .addthis_toolbox {
display: block;
}
```

And for some reason, .addthis_toolbox under the div with the class "title_offeringHope" won't display.

Is there a reason for this? How do I fix this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="h_lft_column">
<h2 class="title_OfferingHope">
<span>Offering Hope &amp; Real Help</span>
</h2>
<p>CONTENT</p>
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:title="Offering Hope & Real Help " addthis:url="URL">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like at300b" fb:like:layout="button_count" title="Send to Facebook_like" href="#">
<fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" href="URL" font="arial" width="90" action="like" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" ref=".T0znaEuo91k.like">
</a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet at300b" title="Tweet" href="#">
<iframe class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="URL" style="width: 109px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button">
</a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" style="display: block;">
<a class="atc_s addthis_button_compact">
<a class="addthis_button_expanded" title="View more services" href="#"></a>
</a>
<div class="atclear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your classes in this order in your CSS document? Try inspecting the element in your browser, and seeing which styles its applying. They're may be a third reference to this class which is overriding.

Comment: @Curt the order shouldn't matter, because the second one has a higher specificity. But yes, there must be more. I suspect this isn't all the CSS either.

Comment: What dialect of HTML is this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no element with class `.addthis_toolbox` inside of your `h2` with class `.title_offeringHope`, that second CSS declaration is null and will be ignored.

Comment: Yes h2 have only span without class inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.h_lft_column .addthis_toolbox {
    display: block;
}
```

"title_offeringHope" is not a parent of "title_offeringHope" in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided, there is no element that references this line in your css:

```
.title_offeringHope .addthis_toolbox
```

What that means is there should be an element with the class `addthis_toolbox`, inside an element with the class `title_offeringHope`. None such element exists.

Answer (score 0):

Class names are case sensitive! So the `<h2 class="title_OfferingHope">` does not match the CSS `.title_offeringHope`.

And see also the other answers. They may be on to something there.

Answer (score 0):

as it's after the title, not inside it, it needs a + to specify the div is following title_offeringHope ;-)

```
.title_offeringHope + .addthis_toolbox 
{
display: block;
}
```